# Using Coffee Script with Active Admin and Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, coffeescript, activeadmin

I'm trying to use the following Coffee Script with my Rails Application and Active Admin.

The problem is Active Admin overrides all the other files. So for example I used to put the script in app/assets/javascripts/visit.js.coffee

and I would usually call it in the new view by placing the following code in 
app/views/visits/new.html.erb

```
$ ->
 $('#visit_guest_id').change ->
   alert "Test"
```

However, Active Admin uses Forms and it kinda overrides the auto populate form when you try to place a new form. So where do I place this code in order to run the script?

What Im trying to accomplish is, every time a different guest is chosen/changed/clicked on from the list/drop down menu, a pop up message will come on screen. Please recommend the best way to accomplish this task in Active Admin even if doesn't include using coffee script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the parenthesis before the "Test" like so.

```
$ ->
   $('#visit_guest_id').change ->
       alert ("Test")
```

There is no need for a semicolon due to it being a form of JQuery ran throughout JavaScript.